# How can make it so only 1 object of type "Ability" can be selected at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an ability system in my game and am running into a few issues. I have set up a script that tells me which "ability" is closest to my cursor and changes the animation state if it is. With one of my abilities, the debug screen says "The closest ability is A" (which works) if selected, but if my cursor is closer to another, it says "The closest ability is A" followed by "The closest ability is B". This is screwing up my animations by triggering selected on both objects when only one should be selected. Where i my code is making this problem occur and how can I fix it so that only 1 ability can be selected at a time.
Thanks in advance!

Closest to cursor script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AtMouseCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ClosestAbility();
        Vector2 cursorPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = cursorPos;
    }
    void ClosestAbility()
    {
        float distanceToClosestAbility = Mathf.Infinity;
        Ability closestAbility = null;
        Ability[] allAbilities = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Ability>();

        foreach (Ability currentAbility in allAbilities)
        {
            float distanceToAbility = (currentAbility.transform.position - this.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
            if (distanceToAbility < distanceToClosestAbility)
            {
                distanceToClosestAbility = distanceToAbility;
                closestAbility = currentAbility;
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The Closest Ability is " + closestAbility.name);
            }


        }
        foreach (Ability currentAbility in allAbilities)
        {
            if (currentAbility != closestAbility)
            {
                currentAbility.GetComponent<Ability>().AbilityNotSelected();
            }
            else if (currentAbility == closestAbility)
            {
                currentAbility.GetComponent<Ability>().AbilitySelected();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ability Script (Goes on ability prefabs)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ability : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void AbilitySelected()
    {
        
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Bruh im selscted");
        anim.SetBool("isSelected", true);
    }

   
    public void AbilityNotSelected()
    {
       
        anim.SetBool("isSelected", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your Log statement outside [after] the first loop.  You won't know that it's actually the closest ability until you've checked all of them.

(And maybe add a check that `allAbilities` isn't null or empty.)

---

Update 1:
`ClosestAbility()` uses `this.transform.position` but `Update()` calls `ClosestAbility()` before updating said transform position.  This looks like it would probably cause you to animate the ability closest to the old mouse position rather than the current mouse position.  But it may not be noticeable if it's called every frame.

Update 2:
Code I had in mind:

```cs
void ClosestAbility()
{
    float distanceToClosestAbility = Mathf.Infinity;
    Ability closestAbility = null;
    Ability[] allAbilities = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Ability>();
    if ((allAbilities == null) || (allAbilities.Length == 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (Ability currentAbility in allAbilities)
    {
        float distanceToAbility = (currentAbility.transform.position - this.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distanceToAbility < distanceToClosestAbility)
        {
            distanceToClosestAbility = distanceToAbility;
            closestAbility = currentAbility;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(closestAbility.name + " is close, but there might be an ability that's closer still");
        }
    }
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("I checked all the abilities and " + closestAbility.name + " is the closest");
    foreach (Ability currentAbility in allAbilities)
    {
        if (currentAbility != closestAbility)
        {
            currentAbility.GetComponent<Ability>().AbilityNotSelected();
        }
        else if (currentAbility == closestAbility)
        {
            currentAbility.GetComponent<Ability>().AbilitySelected();
        }
    }
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Finished updating all the animations without any exceptions");
}
```

Update 3: I'm completely unfamiliar with Unity, but since `currentAbility` *is* an `Ability`, I wonder if the call to `currentAbility.GetComponent<Ability>()` is unnecessary at best and you could/should just have `currentAbility.AbilityNotSelected()`?  Though if your animations ever turn on it must work at least some of the time, maybe.  Still, I'd check if the GetComponent call is returning what you think it's returning.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to coding, how would I do this?

Comment: Sorry this didnt work either. I have 0 clue as to why this is occuring :| thanks for going out of your way to try and help me though!

Answer (score 0):

> UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The Closest Ability is " + closestAbility.name);

You are calling this for each ability in the list consecutively. So,

> if (distanceToAbility < distanceToClosestAbility)

can be true two or more times in your initial foreach loop. The loop itself is fine. Just use

> UnityEngine.Debug.Log("I checked all the abilities and " + closestAbility.name + " is the closest");

this code from IceGlasses code after your first foreach loop to log the closest ability.

The first main problem seems to be the calling

> ClosestAbility();

before updating cursorPos and transform.position. This causes ClosestAbility function to use the transform.position value of the previous frame.

The second problem seems to be calling ClosestAbility function at every frame. So if one of the ability animations take longer than a frame and you move your cursor closer to another ability the second ability will also be triggered.

Unless you stop the first animation when the second animation starts playing OR unless you call ClosestAbility function if none of the animations are playing 2 or more animations can play at the same time.